# Shared library, library dependancy

Tags: c++, linux, linker, compilation, shared-libraries

Is it possible to provide a shared library - which links against another shared library during its creation - transparent to the end user?

As an example of what I mean:

**Shared Library Build**

```
g++ ... `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags` ... `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs`
```

**Desired User Build**

```
g++ file.cc -lfoo
```

Where `libfoo.so.0` is the shared library.

I can only seem to get this to work if the user build includes the `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 ...`. Is there a way, during the creation of the shared object, to allow the end user to not have to worry about the indirect libraries used within `libfoo`?

Comment: is it possible that you are picking-up a static version of the gtk lib istead? If so, it will be required during the user link as well. Otherwise, if it truly is using the shared lib, it shouldn't be required at build time but WILL be required at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a shared library `libABC.so` which links to `libXYZ.so` then,
while creating your `libABC.so`, you have to link with `libXYZ.so`

```
 ld --shared -o libABC.so -L. -lXYZ
```

While compiling the application,

```
gcc app.c -L. -lABC
```

don't forget to, export the library path

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
```

Comment: +1 you can set the `DT_RPATH` as well with `-Wl,-rpath,.` instead of relying on the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environmental variable.